# Can I use already bound instances in Guice's Module.configure()?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'd like to bind a `MethodInterceptor` in my module's `configure()` method, like this:

```
public class DataModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        MethodInterceptor transactionInterceptor = ...;
        binder.bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Transactional.class), null);
    }

    @Provides
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:test");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Provides
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Provides
    public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, new AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the `transactionInterceptor` with the help of Guice, or do I need to create all objects required for my interceptor manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [Guice FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions). From that document:

In order to inject dependencies in an AOP MethodInterceptor, use requestInjection() alongside the standard bindInterceptor() call.

```
public class NotOnWeekendsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    MethodInterceptor interceptor = new WeekendBlocker();
    requestInjection(interceptor);
    bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(NotOnWeekends.class), interceptor);
  }
}
```

Another option is to use Binder.getProvider and pass the dependency in the constructor of the interceptor.

```
public class NotOnWeekendsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    bindInterceptor(any(),
                annotatedWith(NotOnWeekends.class),
                new WeekendBlocker(getProvider(Calendar.class)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how Guice [Persist](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/persist/src/com/google/inject/persist/jpa) was written. Specifically, the [JpaPersistService](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/persist/src/com/google/inject/persist/jpa/JpaPersistModule.java) and its module.